# Change shutdown confirmation timer

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shutdown

I would like to change the timer on the "The system will power off automatically in 60 seconds" dialog. The battery on my device dies about 30 seconds into this message.

There doesn't seem to be a setting for this in the usual places (gsettings, dconf, system settings, etc).

I am not interested in *removing* this dialog or changing the shutdown behavior, I just want to change the amount of time that it waits.

Comment: Another thing: you could also up the percentage when the notice shows up. So not at (for instance) 10% but at 11%, assuming 1% decrease takes more than 30  seconds you need ;)

Answer (score 4):

Remark: hitting the shutdown option TWICE will ignore the timer and shutdown regarding the timer. That might be another option for you.

See

```
/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

Important part:

```
# If the current X console user is running a power management daemon that
# handles suspend/resume requests, let them handle policy This is effectively
# the same as 'acpi-support's '/usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs' file.

[ -r /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs ] && getXconsole
PMS="gnome-settings-daemon kpowersave xfce4-power-manager"
PMS="$PMS guidance-power-manager.py dalston-power-applet"
PMS="$PMS mate-settings-daemon"
PMS="$PMS unity-settings-daemon"
```

Your might have more options (I checked 16.04.4 server ) It has several options in the to test for different desktops. Assuming you are using systemd: [systemd-login](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/systemd-logind.service.8.html) uses  [/etc/systemd/logind.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/logind.conf.5.html) for its settings.

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=12288
```

So I would expect this one:

```
InhibitDelayMaxSec=

Specifies the maximum time a system shutdown or 
sleep request is delayed due to an inhibitor lock of type "delay" 
being active before the inhibitor is ignored and the operation 
executes anyway. Defaults to 5.
```

Comment: Great answer, but what if user wants to click on "virtual" power button in the GNOME interface. User can't make such click twice.

Comment: Just a note: On a "vanilla" Ubuntu 20 (can't remember changing anything), this does nothing

Answer (score 4):

I reported [bug 1782425](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1782425) about your problem to the launchpad.

It affects `gnome-shell`, the timeout is hard-coded somewhere. Did not find right place in code, but the GUI is defined in `gnome-shell-3.28.2/js/ui/endSessionDialog.js`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source gnome-shell
cd gnome-shell-3.28.2

$ grep -ir "The system will power off automatically in .* seconds" -A3
js/ui/endSessionDialog.js:                        "The system will power off automatically in %d seconds.",
js/ui/endSessionDialog.js-                        seconds).format(seconds);
js/ui/endSessionDialog.js-    },
js/ui/endSessionDialog.js-    checkBoxText: C_("checkbox", "Install pending software updates"),
--
```

---

**Small remark.**
It is great that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 19.04 and 19.10 with MATE DE allows user to customize this timeout with values from 0 to 300, for example 20 seconds with

```
gsettings set org.mate.session logout-timeout 20
```

[image: logout-timeout in MATE]

(or from `dconf-editor`).

Comment: Unfortunately, after move [the issue to Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/issues/369), they closed it.